# Pandas regex returns values in brackets

Tags: python, regex, pandas, gps

My data frame column is dtype: object. It contains GPS coordinates I want to extract and place in a longitude and latitude column. The regex results are wrapped in *open and *closing brackets. Why? How can I remove? Am I using the wrong pattern?

[image: Jupyter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add `.apply(', '.join)`
join is iterating over your list items and join them with the selected delimiter  ***', '*** (you could use ' ' as well). apply is used to pass the join function to your pandas column.
you can find additional info about pandas apply [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
dfp['latitude\longitude'].str.findall(pattern).apply(', '.join)
```